# GET request every 300 meters

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I'm using MapKit and Cllocationmanager to show the user's location on the map when driving. I also do a `GET` request to show some locations on the map. However, my `GET` request is retrieving locations within 1km radius, and I have to constantly do other requests when user change location by at least 300m. How can I make `GET` requests when user change location by 300m?

I tried to put the `GET` request in the "didUpdateLocations" and set the value `locationManager.distanceFilter = 300` but that caused delay on updating the user's location on the map.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not keep the last used (for the request) location (let's call it `previousSavedLocation`, and in `didUpdateLocations:`, check the distance from it, and if it's greater to 300m, do the GET request, and then set previousSavedLocation to the current one?

Comment: I thought by doing this "for loop", it will consume a lot of energy because I am constantly checking the user's location.

Comment: If `didUpdateLocations:` is called, the check **already ran**.

Comment: But I have " manager.stopUpdatingLocation()" as the first line in the "didUpdateLocations" so it's not looping all the time. I monitor the user's location by "mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow"